# Sorted sets and comparators

Tags: java, set, treeset

I'm working with a `TreeSet`that is meant to store pathfind locations used during the execution of a A* algorithm.

Basically until there are "open" elements (still to be exhaustively visited) the neighbours of every open element are taken into consideration and added to a `SortedSet`that keeps them ordered by their cost and heuristic cost. This means that I have a class like:

```
public class PathTileInfo implements Comparable<PathTileInfo>
{
  int cost;
  int hCost;
  final int x, y;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(PathTileInfo t2) {
    int c = cost + hCost;
    int c2 = t2.cost + t2.hCost;
    int costComp = c < c2 ? -1 : (c > c2 ? 1: 0);

    return costComp != 0 ? costComp : (x < t2.x || y < t2.y ? -1 : (x > t2.x || y > t2.y ? 1 : 0));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o2) {
    if (o2 instanceof PathTileInfo) {
      PathTileInfo i = (PathTileInfo)o2;
      return i.cost + i.hCost == cost + hCost && x == i.x && y == i.y;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

In this way first the total cost is considered, then, since a total ordering is needed (consistency with equals) a ordering according to the x,y coordinate is taken into account.

This should work but simply it doesn't, if I iterate over the TreeSet during the algorithm execution like in

```
for (PathTileInfo t : openSet)
  System.out.print("("+t.x+","+t.y+","+(t.cost+t.hCost)+") ");
```

I get results in which the right ordering is not kept, eg:

> (7,7,6) (7,6,7) (6,8,6) (6,6,7) (5,8,7) (5,7,7) (6,7,6) (6,6,7) (6,5,7) (5,7,7) (5,5,8) (4,7,7) (4,6,8) (4,5,8)

is there something subtle I am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: That code all looks fine...can you post the relevant parts of the A* algorithm that create and maintain the open set? It might be something external causing the problem. Might also be worth putting some debugging statements in the `compareTo` method to check that the comparison is being performed correctly.

Comment: Have you overridden `hashCode` so that it is consistent with `equals`? It's a bit of a long shot but that could be the problem. In any case, you should always make sure that `equals` and `hashCode` are consistent.

Comment: I don't have an answer coming to me immediately, only a comment: as a general rule I implement the equals() method using the compareTo() method, so that the exact same logic is used in both places.  I find it easier to uncover comparison-related bugs this way.

Comment: i looked at the code of TreeMap (which is internally used by TreeSet) and it is using Comparator and not equals() when u add an element to TreeSet. FYI

Comment: You have implemented Comparable, but you do not get the expected order when you put these objects in a TreeSet. The only logical reason is because your compareTo method is not implemented correctly.
Write a Junit test to verify the compareTo method works as you think it should. I can't tell myself, because I find your code difficult to read. There are way too many logical operators (nested ternary? come on!) in one statement to be readable. I'm sure your problem is in those lines. Are you that sure you know the order of operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure NOT to change **'Comparable' value** of element **after adding** to the `TreeSet`. If you change the value after adding to the `TreeSet`, `TreeSet` cannot maintain the new order.

I think your `PathTileInfo` is correct, although `equals()` override is not necessary in this case.

Comment: If you override any of `equals`, `hashCode` or `compareTo` then it's good practice to override *all* of them. Otherwise you are likely to run into weird bugs as soon as you use your object in a `HashSet` or any kind of ordered data structure (e.g. `TreeSet` or a sorted list).

Comment: @Cameron: It is "Always override hashcode when you override equals". Since PathTileInfo doesn't override hashcode, override equals is not necessary. But it's good practice as you said.

Comment: I think Shengyuan might be onto something.  If the values of cost or hCost are changing after the object has been put into a TreeSet, the set will no longer be correctly ordered and I don't think there's anyway to reorder the set other than creating a new TreeSet out of the old one.  I just did a quick test of this using your code and it would explain the symptom you are seeing.

Comment: It actually was the problem, I though that the `TreeSet` would sort itself again when an element is added but I was wrong. I had to switch to a plain `Set` instead that a `SortedSet` and searched for minimum value by iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet by default orders the elements you add using natural ordering and this is what is happening in your case. Are you telling TreeSet to use your custom comparator when creating it?

Comment: I don't get it, if the elements that I insert in the `TreeSet` implement a custom comparator (like in my case) why should I warn the `TreeSet` about using a different comparator? I already replace the default one..

Comment: The `PathTileInfo` class implements `Comparable` so there is no custom comparator.

Comment: Yes but I provide my own implementation of `compareTo`, that one should override the default natural ordering one or what?

Comment: As documentation of __Comparable<T>__ class states: "Objects that implement this interface can be used as keys in a sorted map or as elements in a sorted set, without the need to specify a comparator."

Comment: @Jack: Yes, it should. When I say there is no custom comparator, I mean you are not creating an instance of `Comparator`. Your objects define a natural ordering so an explicit `Comparator` is not needed. Not sure *why* you are seeing the bug, but it's not because you're lacking a `Comparator`.

Comment: Jack - you are correct. I looked at the code of TreeSet and the default constructor creates a TreeMap internally that depends on the compareTo(...) implemented by the keys. Did u try to debug the point in code where you are calling add(...)?